# Response Listener didn't work

Tags: android, google-maps, android-volley, android-json

I'm newbie in Android world.

I met some trouble using Volley Response.Listener.
I don't no why the json didn't catch the Result, whereas when i'm manually execute the json URL, it goes well.
Please give me some help to find where's the problem.
this is My code :

### MAIN ACTIVITY.java :

```
package com.mitrainfotek.locationlistener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Marker mMarker;
private GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
private LocationListener mListener;
private LocationRequest request;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    request = new LocationRequest();
    //request = LocationRequest.create();
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    request.setInterval(3000);
    request.setFastestInterval(1000);

    mLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ready To Map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    mListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            UpdateLoc(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        }
    };
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, request, mListener);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.w("LatLng", connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mListener);
}

public void UpdateLoc(double Lat, double Lng) {
    Log.w("LatLng","Start UpdateLoc");

    // Login
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.w("LatLng", "WUANJEEEEENGG");
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                Log.w("LatLng", String.valueOf(success));

                // Sukses
                if (success == true) {
                    Log.w("LatLng","Success");
                    // Failed
                } else {
                    Log.w("LatLng","Failed");
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.w("LatLng", "Failed : " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    };

    // temporary Force Parameters
    UpdateLoc updateLoc = new UpdateLoc("mloc_insert", "46", "-6.23434", "106.823423", responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    queue.add(updateLoc);
    }
}
```

### UPDATELOC.java :

```
package com.mitrainfotek.locationlistener;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by MAULANA on 6/28/2016.
 */
public class UpdateLoc extends StringRequest {
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/pangkut.com/pang_function.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public UpdateLoc (String funcName, String user_no, String lat, String lng, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);

    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("funcName", funcName);
    params.put("user_no", user_no);
    params.put("lat", lat);
    params.put("lng", lng);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
    }
}
```

### ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mitrainfotek.tespeta.MapsActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### ANDROIDMANIFEST.XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mitrainfotek.locationlistener">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="*****MY_KEY****" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

### BUILD.GRADLE :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mitrainfotek.locationlistener"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

many thanks for any help.

Comment: You should also create Volley Error Listener. See what error is it

Comment: Are you receiving any specific error?

Comment: Thanks Mark for the Clue.

Comment: @intj after create volley error listener, yes it is, and problem solved. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

you can add a parameter when your instantiate(object) your updateloc. aside from passing in your four parameteters and a responseListener, add in another parameter which takes in your url. also add this paramter to your updateLoc constructor

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.